# Android JB broadcast receiver not receiving bluetooth.android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am using a rooted samsung galaxy nexus phone running jb and for some reason I am not receiving any broadcast intents from the bluetooth connection service. Below you will find my receiver manifest and the broadcast receiver code. Any tips or ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Here is the Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".ABroadcastReciever" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED" />
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED" />
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND" />
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING" />
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED" />
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Here is the Reciever

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
            String action = intent.getAction();

            //This is looking for the Wifi Connectivity Changes
            if(action.equals("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")){
                Log.d(TAG,"received: Wifi Connection Change");          
            }
            //This is looking Bluetooth connection disconnect 
            else if(action.equals("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED") ||
            action.equals("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED_REQUESTED") ){
                Log.d(TAG,"Received: Bluetooth Disconnected");

            }
            //This is looking for Bluetooth connection established
            else if(action.equals("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED")){
    Log.d(TAG,"Received: Bluetooth Connected");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try the same app on pre-JB?  In other words, is it JB that's the problem or the above code?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the new intent that is being broadcast.

```
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED" />
```

Thanks for lookin
here is the new Intent

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I am correct, but I think that this line is wrong:

```
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED" />
```

It should be this one:

```
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED" />
```

Same thing with the others. Change "BluetoothDevice" for "device".

Also same thing similar in broascast :

```
if(action.equals("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED"))
```

Should be

```
if(action.equals("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED"))
```

Change BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED for device.action.ACL_CONNECTED

Comment: Thank you so much! Wasted hours figuring out why my BroadcastReceiver registered dynamicaly received the actions but not the static one defined in manifest.

Comment: This solution does not work for me (Nexus 6 Lollipop). See my answer for an updated solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your intent filter actions are incorrect. You actually want to use the following:

`<action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />`

You can find these values in [official Android BluetoothDevice documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED) (look under constant value).